# Why there is a phantom contact points in my Box2d libgdx game

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'am writing game using `libgdx` and `box2d`. When an object touches another, phantom contact points often occur. This is how i drawing contact points:

```
private void renderContactPoints() {
    for (Contact contact : world.getContactList())
        for (Vector2 point : contact.getWorldManifold().getPoints())
            renderer.getBatch().draw(tex, point.x * PPM, point.y * PPM, 20, 20);

}
```

Screenshot of problem

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: Which contact points are the phantom contact points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance **Box2D** and **libGDX** re-uses arrays to avoid reallocation, therefore you cannot iterate the full result of  `getContactList` and `getPoints` as you'll get too many results.

Instead, query the number of items first:

```
private void renderContactPoints() {
    for(int i = 0; i < world.getContactCount(); ++i) {
        Contact contact = world.getContactList().get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < contact.getWorldManifold().getNumberOfContactPoints(); ++j) {
            Vector2 point = contact.getWorldManifold().getPoints()[j];
            renderer.getBatch().draw(tex, point.x * PPM, point.y * PPM, 20, 20);
        }
    }
}
```